# Need help to split one column(subrow) in csv file into two columns or three columns using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, split

I have this csv file with this example of value:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gam2o.png)

I want to divide the column "Intakt inkl moms Artikelnummer  based on that semi column into two -three columns for example (obs: also need to divide for other column as well, cause the data is not in order

```
Ordernummer:96049
Intakt inkl moms: 73,00
Artikelnummer1: 27404475
Ordernummer:96050
Intakt inkl moms: 536,00
Artikelnummer1: 82047448
Artikelnummer2:75109997
```

This is what I wrote initially

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
 df = pd.read_csv('orderexport_new.csv', encoding='latin1')

# Initialize empty lists to store the split values
Intakt_inkl_moms = {}
Artikelnr1 = {}
Artikelnr2 = {}
ordernummer_list = {}

# Iterate through each row in the DataFrame
 for index, row in df.iterrows():
# Split the values in the "Intakt inkl moms" column
 values = row['Intakt inkl moms'].split(';')
 num_values = len(values)

# Determine the number of values and append them to the corresponding lists
if num_values >= 1:
    Intakt_inkl_moms.append(values[0])
else:
    Intakt_inkl_moms.append(None)
    
if num_values >= 2:
    Artikelnr1.append(values[1])
else:
    Artikelnr1.append(None)
    
if num_values >= 3:
    Artikelnr2.append(values[2])
else:
    Artikelnr2.append(None)
    
# Append the ordernummer to maintain alignment
 ordernummer_list.append(row['Ordernummer'])

# Add the new columns to the DataFrame
 df['Intakt_inkl_moms'] = Intakt_inkl_moms
 df['Artikelnr1'] = Artikelnr1
 df['Artikelnr2'] = Artikelnr2
 df['Ordernummer'] = ordernummer_list

# Drop the original "Intakt inkl moms" column
#
# df.drop(['Intakt inkl moms'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# Save the modified DataFrame to a new CSV file
 df.to_csv('ny_orderdata.csv', index=False)

# Print the DataFrame to verify the changes
print(df)
```

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RYSI.png)

PLs guide me and write down the code also, thanks alot!

Comment: You'll likely have a bad time trying to read a file where each datum is essentially two or more rows with just Pandas. I'd recommend to read the file line by line using the `csv` module and regroup your data first.

Comment: @jezrael Bad duplicate – OP's data has a header-row+subrow(s) structure.

Comment: yes@AKX data has header -subrow(s) structure, what is your solution in this case ? thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle this is to process each line of the CSV yourself, and catch the missing Ordernummer.

- Read each line, if it has an Ordernummer, create a new record in the output
- If it does not have an Ordernummer, update the last record you added with new fields with only the fields you care about in the record
- Keep track of the highest number of fields added so that headers for the output CSV can be generated
- Write the CSV yourself, or create a `pandas.DataFrame` to continue processing in a more familiar way

I recommend using python's builtin `csv` library, as it handles alot of things well like various newlines, different separators, etc, and can save you some headache.

Disclaimer: I have no idea what any of the words are, I just kept them as-is from the question body.

Here is a mockup that matches your request, to adapt it to your needs simply update `columns_to_split` and `columns_to_split_names` to match your use case:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

def _main():
    # In file name
    fname = 'orderexport_new.csv'
    # Out file name
    outname = 'ny_orderdata.csv'
    # Which columns do you want to add to new columns?
    columns_to_split = [1, 3]
    # What names to give those new columns?
    columns_to_split_names = ['Artikelnummer', 'Artikelns styckpris inkl moms']
    out_data = []
    # This is to track what the fields in the final CSV should be
    max_cols = None  # (max_cur_artikelnummer, columns_in_that_max_entry)

    with open(fname) as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        # Read the two headers first
        headers1 = next(csvreader)
        headers2 = next(csvreader)
        # Iterate through each row in the CSV
        for row in csvreader:
            # Check if there is a value in the first cell
            #   This relies on the cell being empty, if it is some other thing,
            #   then you should modify this check for that
            if row[0]:  # This row has a new Ordernummer
                # Create a small dict with the headers matched to their field values
                new_record = {header_name: field_value for header_name, field_value in zip(headers1, row)}
                out_data.append(new_record)
                # Reset the sub row counter
                cur_artikelnummer = 0
            else:  # This row does not have a new Ordernummer
                # Increment the cur_artikelnummer so that the columns get a new number
                cur_artikelnummer += 1
                # Iterate through each one so that you can add as many as you want above
                for i, column_to_split in enumerate(columns_to_split):
                    out_data[-1][f'{columns_to_split_names[i]}_{cur_artikelnummer}'] = row[column_to_split]
                # If this is the greatest value so far, update so that the CSV headers can be written
                if not max_cols or max_cols[0] < cur_artikelnummer:
                    max_cols = (cur_artikelnummer, out_data[-1].keys())

    # To create a similar CSV
    with open(outname, 'w', newline='\n') as fh:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(fh)
        # csvwriter.writerow(headers1)
        # csvwriter.writerow(headers2)
        csvwriter.writerow(max_cols[1])
        for row in out_data:
            csvwriter.writerow(row.values())

    # If you want a pandas dataframe instead:
    df = pd.DataFrame(out_data, columns=list(max_cols[1]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main()
```

Here is my replicated input:

| Ordernummer | "Intakt inkl moms" | "Valutajusterad Intakt inkl moms" | "Dynamisk valutajusterad" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Artikelnummer | Antal | "Artikelns styckpris inkl moms" |
| 96049 | 73.00 | 745.69 | 736.95 |
|  | 27404475 | 1 | 678.9 |
| 96050 | 536.0 | 536.0 | 536.0 |
|  | 82047448 | 1 | 310 |
|  | 75109997 | 1 | 158 |
| 96051 | 6073.0 | 6073.0 | 6073.0 |
|  | 695352 | 2 | 3072.0 |
| 96052 | 550.0 | 556.65 | 564.74 |
|  | 737-188-00 | 1 | 378.9 |
| 96053 | 550.0 | 556.65 | 564.74 |

Here is my output from the code shown above:

| Ordernummer | Intakt inkl moms | Valutajusterad Intakt inkl moms | Dynamisk valutajusterad | Artikelnummer_1 | Artikelns styckpris inkl moms_1 | Artikelnummer_2 | Artikelns styckpris inkl moms_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 96049 | 73.00 | 745.69 | 736.95 | 27404475 | 678.9 |  |  |
| 96050 | 536.0 | 536.0 | 536.0 | 82047448 | 310 | 75109997 | 158 |
| 96051 | 6073.0 | 6073.0 | 6073.0 | 695352 | 3072.0 |  |  |
| 96052 | 550.0 | 556.65 | 564.74 | 737-188-00 | 378.9 |  |  |
| 96053 | 550.0 | 556.65 | 564.74 |  |  |  |  |

Let me know if you have any questions.